# Wait for background image fadeOut to finish before fadeIn executes when hovering on menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Q: I have a content page with an empty div inside it that fades in different background images depending on which menu item is hovering over. My question is how I can wait for the current background image to fadeOut before the current menu item is hovering on is allowed to fadeIn. Currently, if I hover to quickly over another menu item the fadeIn background image animation is behaving like it's already happened.

You can see my solution and description image below.

[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W4PS.png)

HTML

```
<div class="bg"></div>

          <a id="first" href="{{ url('example') }}" class="buttonlink">

                   <div class="buttontitle">

                    <h1 class="buttontitleinner">example</h1>

                     <p class="buttoncaption">example</p>

                 </div>
            </a>

          <a id="second" href="{{ url('example2') }}" class="buttonlink">

                   <div class="buttontitle">

                    <h1 class="buttontitleinner">example2</h1>

                     <p class="buttoncaption">example2</p>

                 </div>
            </a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#first").hover(function () {

    $(".bg").css("background-image", 'url("./img1.png")').stop().animate({'opacity': 0.25}, 300);

    },function(){

    $(".bg").css("background-image", 'url("./img1.png")').stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);

});


$("#second").hover(function () {

    $(".bg").css("background-image", 'url("./img2.png")').stop().animate({'opacity': 0.25}, 300);

    },function(){   

    $(".bg").css("background-image", 'url("./img2.png")').stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);

});
```

Questions? Just ask.

Thanks beforehand!

///E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `.stop()`, but before calling `.animate()` to fade the image in, set the `opacity` to `0`. That way the fade-in animation will completely run. Otherwise, the opacity may already be at `0.25`, so it won't run.

```
$(".bg").css("background-image", 'url("./img1.png")').stop().css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 300);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksw1fs90/)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for solutions involving promise() and callbacks and whatnot... I'm glad the solution was this simple :) All the best!